# Javascript onclick, how to have different alpha for some elements?

Tags: javascript, html, css

On click event changes every column's background color and it works. But there's the html-body background color that I want to have different (only opacity). Now it gives the same color for body.background (last line) like other columns. Instead of that I want body to have the same color, but 0.5 Opacity, so the elements on top, that have opacity 1, would stand out nicely.

```
function BackgroundColorChange(){
        // the main opacity level
        var a = 1;
        // some colors chosen for DOM elements backgrounds
        var blue = 'rgba(51, 102, 153,'+a+')';
        var grey = 'rgba(66, 82, 102,'+a+')';
        var darkgreen = 'rgba(25, 102, 102,'+a+')';
        var lightgreen = 'rgba(62, 116, 89,'+a+')';
        var brown = 'rgba(96, 86, 57,'+a+')';
        var purple = 'rgba(66, 36, 51,'+a+')';

        var colorSelection = [blue, grey, darkgreen, lightgreen, brown, purple];

        // pick the random color for background as the event is clicked
        var color = colorSelection[Math.floor(Math.random() * colorSelection.length)];

        // the elements i want to have 'opacity = 1' are selected here
        var subsection = document.querySelectorAll(".childElement-column-photo, .childElement-sub-section, .sub-section, .modal-header, .modal-footer");

                for (var i = 0; i < subsection.length; i++) {
                      subsection[i].style.backgroundColor = color;
                }

        a = 0.5; //? ? ? ? ? 

        // I want this body element to have the same color but with 0.5 opacity
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = color;
}
```

I have tried to play around while defining 'a' for opacity, but it didn't work.

HTML:
this is mainly how my html is tagged.

```
    <a onclick="BackgroundColorChange();" href="#">ChangeColor</a>

    <body onload="setInterval(BackgroundColorChange(), 50000)">

    // there are many elements with this class name
    <div class="childElement-column-photo">
```

Comment: can you post a little bit of html please, just want to see how it interacts.

Comment: Your `setInterval` call doesn't actually work; you aren't passing anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion is the following the best solution:

Try to save the rgb color as an array and build your css property on the fly.

```
function buildRgbaCSSProperty(color, alpha) {
  return  'rgba(' + color[0] + ', ' + color[1] + ', ' + color[2] + ', '+ alpha + ')';
}

function BackgroundColorChange(){
          // the main opacity level
        var a = 1;
        // some colors chosen for DOM elements backgrounds
        var blue = [51, 102, 153];
        var grey = [66, 82, 102];
        var darkgreen = [25, 102, 102];
        var lightgreen = [62, 116, 89];
        var brown = [96, 86, 57];
        var purple = [66, 36, 51];

        var colorSelection = [blue, grey, darkgreen, lightgreen, brown, purple];

        // pick the random color for background as the event is clicked
        var color = colorSelection[Math.floor(Math.random() * colorSelection.length)];

        // the elements i want to have 'opacity = 1' are selected here
        var subsection = document.querySelectorAll(".childElement-column-photo, .childElement-sub-section, .sub-section, .modal-header, .modal-footer");

                for (var i = 0; i < subsection.length; i++) {
                      subsection[i].style.backgroundColor = buildRgbaCSSProperty(color, a);
                }

        a = 0.5; //? ? ? ? ? 

        // I want this body element to have the same color but with 0.5 opacity
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = buildRgbaCSSProperty(color, a);
}
```

Comment: Even though this is working, I don't get this line.

         `return  'rgba(' + color[0] + ', ' + color[1] + ', ' + color[2] + ', '+ alpha + ')';`

From the code I see it's taking 'rgba(' + blue + ', ' + grey + ', ' +darkgreen + ', '+ alpha + ')';

does it take colors from array, isn't it supposed to mix them? how does it generate the color I want?

Comment: your color is an array with 3 indexes. For example we take blue. Your `color[0]` is 51, `color[1]` is 102 and `color[2]` is 153. Your output from the code is at the end: `rgba(51, 102, 153, ' + alpha + ');` and this is the same string as your variable :)

Answer (score 2):

By the time you are attempting to set `a = 0.5` you've already made the color variables, and they contain a string, and not a reference to the `a` variable, so they wont change.

You'll need to separate the opacity value from the rest of the color value, and add it on at the time you're handing it to an element's background color.

```
   var blue = '51, 102, 153,';
```

You could save your strings as this, and then when you set style, pass in

`'rgba(' + color + a +')'`

Answer (score 1):

You have to modify the "alpha" channel of the RGBA color to be .5 and you can do that by splitting the RGBA value you have, at the commas, into an array. Then, you replace the last value and then put the string back together again.

```js
function BackgroundColorChange(){
        // the main opacity level
        var a = 1;
        // some colors chosen for DOM elements backgrounds
        var blue = 'rgba(51, 102, 153,'+a+')';
        var grey = 'rgba(66, 82, 102,'+a+')';
        var darkgreen = 'rgba(25, 102, 102,'+a+')';
        var lightgreen = 'rgba(62, 116, 89,'+a+')';
        var brown = 'rgba(96, 86, 57,'+a+')';
        var purple = 'rgba(66, 36, 51,'+a+')';

        var colorSelection = [blue, grey, darkgreen, lightgreen, brown, purple];

        // pick the random color for background as the event is clicked
        var color = colorSelection[Math.floor(Math.random() * colorSelection.length)];

        // the elements i want to have 'opacity = 1' are selected here
        var subsection = document.querySelectorAll(".childElement-column-photo, .childElement-sub-section, .sub-section, .modal-header, .modal-footer");

                for (var i = 0; i < subsection.length; i++) {
                      subsection[i].style.backgroundColor = color;
                }

        // Split the rgba string into an array separated at the commas
        var alpha = color.split(",");
        
        // Change the last value to desired (the close parenthesis is needed)
        alpha[3] = ".5)";
        
        // put elements back into a string
        color = alpha.join(',');
        
        // Test
        console.log(color);

        // I want this body element to have the same color but with 0.5 opacity
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = color;
}

BackgroundColorChange();
```